# My Arraylist is null in oncreate

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I'm programming with android studio and I want to parse a json and put the details in my object in a function in MainActivity and I do it well in that function and every thing is ok! But when I want to use it in onCreate it's null.
What should I do?
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 ArrayList<Details> details= new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new myserver2().execute("");
    Adapter adptor=new Adapter(this,details);
    ListView l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    l.setAdapter(adptor);

}
private class myserver2 extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String s;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet hp = new HttpGet("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        try

        {
            HttpResponse r = client.execute(hp);
            HttpEntity ent = r.getEntity();
            String s = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                Details d = new Details();
                obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
                d.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("id")));
                d.setUserid(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("userId")));
                d.setBody(obj.getString("body"));
                d.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                Log.i("**(*", obj.getString("title"));
                details.add(d);
            }

            Log.i("**(*", details.get(0).getTitle());

        } catch (
                IOException e
                )

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (
                JSONException e
                )

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Details:

```
public class Details {
int id=0,userid=0;
String body,title;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(int userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

My log after the for in myserver given the true title but if I had this Log in onCreate it throws an exception:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
And it's because of my Arraylis is null in onCreate but why and what should I do,I dont know!

Comment: Why its a candidate for upvote? OP is simply missing the basics of `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `onPostExecute()` method inside your `AsyncTask` and you can set the adapter there normally. Add this code inside `myserver2` class

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    super.onPostExecute(message);

    Adapter adptor=new Adapter(MainActivity.this,details);
    ListView l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    l.setAdapter(adptor);
}
```

and remove those 3 lines from your `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your onCreates tries to access the arraylist while the asyc task is not finished. To mamke sure you set the adapter only after asyc task is finished, set the adapter inside `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{ 
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  if(details.size > 0){
    Adapter adptor=new Adapter(this,details);
    l.setAdapter(adptor);
}else{
  l.setAdapter(null);
}
```

}

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in `asynctask` `Onpost()` method
because some time network operation take time to get date but

```
Adapter adptor=new Adapter(this,details);
l.setAdapter(adptor);
```

Answer (score 0):

since onPostExecute-Method from AsyncTask is called within your main UI-Thread, you can initialize you listview and adapter in onPostExecute-Method.

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    super.onPostExecute(message);

    Adapter adptor=new Adapter(MainActivity.this,details);
    ListView l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    l.setAdapter(adptor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this in your oncreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Adapter adptor=new Adapter(this,details);
    ListView l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    l.setAdapter(adptor);
    new myserver2().execute("");
}
```

and add this method in your AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    super.onPostExecute(message);
    adpter.notifydatasetchanged()
}
```